# CGAffineTransformMakeScaleで拡縮したViewにaddSubviewしている部品のFrameが知りたい

Tags: objective-c

部品A上の決まった位置に部品Bを乗せて、部品Aを拡縮すれば部品Bも合わせて拡縮されるようにしたく、さらに拡縮された後の部品BのFrameも知りたいです。
（例えば、「ビルが並んでいる画像」の「一番左のビルの右端」に「看板の画像」を乗せて、「ビルが並んでいる画像」の拡縮率で「一番左のビルの右端」の位置は変わらず「看板の画像」も大きくしたい）

部品AをCGAffineTransformMakeScaleで部品Bごと拡縮し、拡縮後のFrameを確認したところ、部品Aのframe.sizeは変更されてましたが、部品Bに変化はありませんでした。
実行後の見た目はちゃんと拡縮されて、位置もサイズも変わっているように見えるのですが、NSLogでframeを出力してみると変化がありません。

拡縮後の部品Bのframeを確認できる方法はありますか？

以下サンプルコード

```
// ビルが並んでいる画像ビュー
UIImageView *a = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxxxx"]];

[self.view addSubview:a];

// 看板の画像ビュー
UIImageView *b = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxxxx"]];
// 一番左のビルの右端に来るように部品Aの画像サイズから座標を指定
b.frame = CGRectMake(363, 420, 100, 600);

[a addSubview:b];


// 部品Bごと大きさを変える
// 画面幅を画像と同じ大きさのビューの幅で割って、どのくらい縮小すれば良いか調べる
double raito = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / CGRectGetWidth(a.frame);
// 縮小する
a.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(raito, raito);
// transformしたことにより位置が変化するので左上に戻す
a.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, a.frame.size.width, a.frame.size.height);

NSLog(@"a Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(a.frame));
NSLog(@"b Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(b.frame));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGAffineTransform`のAffine Transformは、訳せば「座標変換」です。つまり、オブジェクトの面積を拡大縮小するのではなくて、座標の目盛りの取り方を、拡大縮小します。ですから、Subviewの座標情報が変化しないのは、むしろ自然な結果です。
座標変換前の座標で、拡大縮小後のSubviewの座標情報（位置と大きさ）を得ようとするなら、プロパティ`transform`を変更していないSuperviewを基準にします。それには、`UIView`のメソッド`- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view`を使います。

```
CGFloat raito = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / CGRectGetWidth(a.frame);
a.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(raito, raito);
a.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, a.frame.size.width, a.frame.size.height);
// b.frameを、aビュー基準から、self.view基準に変換する。
CGRect newFrame = [self.view convertRect: b.frame fromView: a];

NSLog(@"b Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
```

---

ご質問に対してではなく、質問者さんのやりたいことに対して、おまけのアドバイスをしておきます。
`CGAffineTransform`による座標変換では、Viewの`center`（中心点）が基準点（座標の原点）になって、拡大縮小、回転しますが、`CALayer`のプロパティ`anchorPoint`を変更することで、基準点を変えることができます。

```
a.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

例えば、これでビュー`a`の左上端を基準にして、拡大縮小します。`CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)`にすると、右下端が基準点になります。Subview`b`の位置になるように`anchorPoint`を調整すると、シンプルなコードにすることができるでしょう。
このように、**Core Animation**の`CALayer`クラスを一度、かんたんにでも勉強なさることをお勧めします。